Extending $f(z)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(n!)^{-1}z^{n!}$
Show that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(n!)^{-1}z^{n!}$ describes an analytic function $f$ in $\Delta(0,1)$. Suppose $D$ is any domain that properly includes $\Delta(0,1)$, then show that there is no analytic $F:D\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ s.t. the restriction of $F$ in $\Delta (0,1)$ coincides with $f$
I know how to show that the series converge in the disk, and I also know how to show the analycity of $f$. But I don't see any issues with having such $F$. I've tried to compute the derivative of $F$ and see what happens at the boundary of $\Delta(0,1)$. But I wasn't able to derive any contradictions. How should I show that $F$ can't exist?

@RyszardSzwarc It means that $\Delta (0,1)$ is in $D$, but $\Delta (0,1)\neq D$

@RyszardSzwarc here domain is defined as a connected and open set.

This follows from Ostrowski-Hadamard gap theorem (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ostrowski%E2%80%93Hadamard_gap_theorem), but I don’t know if that’s the answer you are looking for.

An easy proof goes like this; assume there is such a domain and such an $F$, so there is $|w|=1$ st $f$ extends analytically on a small neighborhood of $w$; then take $g(z)=zf'(z)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}z^{n!}$ which also extends analytically at $w$ so in particular is continuous and has a finite limit from inside the unit circle on a small unit circle arc containing $w$; but for any rational number $p/q, q \ge 1$ one has $|g(re^{i\pi p/q})| \to \infty$ as $r \to 1$ since all the terms from say $n=q+2$ on are $r^{n!}\to 1, r \to 1$ since $e^{i\pi p(q+2)!/q}=1$. However $e^{i\pi p/q}$ are dense in the unit circle, so we can find such in any arc however small around any $|w|=1$ and that is a contradiction.
